# Designing login system with different roles

Tags: database-design

I am designing a database that is for a clinic management system using mysql DBMS,
Clinic Owner can have an account through which he can give access to all staff or a specific persons to access clinic account depending on the permissions that granted to that user

I have the following tables:

- Users Table

  - user_id
  - email
  - username
- Managers Table.

  - user_id_fk
- Doctors Table.

  - user_id_fk
- Nurses Table.

  - user_id_fk
- Employee Table.

  - user_id_fk
- Permissions Table.

  - user_id_fk

The user which can be manager or doctor or nurse or employee can login to the clinic system with the permissions granted for this user depending  on Permissions Table. .

So Here is the situation should i create a foreign key that links all sub tables (managers nurses doctors employee) with a foreign key with the Users table which linked to permission USING THE APPROACH "POLYMORPHIC ASSOCIATION" or sould i separate them and remove table Users and make permissions linked to each table separately,and if you have other suggestions let me know

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to answer

Comment: What info you need me to add ?

Comment: Both are valid solutions from a database design point of view for a supervlass - subclass problem. You need to make your mind up which approach to use.

Comment: @Shadow which solution you will choose if you are designing that databaee that accepts more flexiblity in the future.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is no catch all answer to your question! If there was, we would already have suggested it. There are certain qestions where you just have to make a call yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would have three tables: Users, Roles, and Permissions.
In the roles table, I would create Doctors, Nurses, etc... And assign there the required permissions. Then give that role to the user.
Each protected resource will be permission checked and show only what is allowed, based on their permissions that have been assigned in their role.

Example Tables:

USERS

| id | firstname | lastname | role_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brat | Pitt | 1 |
| 2 | Angelina | Jolie | 2 |

ROLES

| id | name | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Doctor |  |
| 2 | Nurse |  |

PERMISSIONS

| id | name | description | role_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | view_section_a | ... | 1 |
| 2 | view_section_b | ... | 1 |
| 3 | edit_section_b | ... | 1 |
| 4 | view_page_x | ... | 2 |

Comment: Do you mean making the Roles Table as the Superclass and assign Doctors nurses etc as their Subclasses and link each user with a role from the Roles Table

Comment: As i want a separate table for each type of user to give me more flexiblity

Comment: Not exactly, I've added some example tables to my answer to show you what I mean. 
I think this structure has full flexibility. Let me know if there are cases where this will not work for you.

Comment: what if there is table that only be associated with nurses table and another table that will be linked to only doctors table should i link it to role where there may be doctor_role_1, doctor_role_2 ,and other different types of roles  or should i link to the users table where one column should refer to one table not in all rows